# $K:=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}dx$ integral $K.M.N$ Who is the biggest and who is the smallest?

Tags: integration, reference-request

Set 
   $$M:=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{((1+x)^2)}{(1+x^2)}dx$$
 $$N:=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(1+x)}{(e^{x})}dx$$
$$K:=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}  {1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}dx$$
integral $K.M.N$ Who is the biggest and who is the smallest?

Comment: @coffeemath yes  I didn't notice it before, I got it wrong.

Comment: @coffeemath yes This is obvious

Comment: I don't know why the upper and lower are red.Can you help me?

Comment: What should they say?

Comment: LaTeX is interpreting \2 and \- as commands, which is why they are red. Do you mean $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ perhaps?

Comment: @cmk ？？？What do you mean?

Comment: @Wojowu that's what I'm thinking, too.

Comment: @Wojowu yes That's it.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to see that:$$M=\pi,N<\pi,K>\pi.$$
Please note that:
$\frac{((1+x)^2)}{(1+x^2)}=1+\frac{2x}{1+x^2},$ $\frac{1+x}{e^x}<1$, $1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}>1$.

Comment: You are a big god, you found the focus, but unfortunately I lack background knowledge.

Comment: $$M:=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(2x)}{(1+x^2)}dx$$ Why is it equal to 0

Comment: $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ is an odd function!

Comment: you are amazing! I noticed that you are Chinese.Can I add a WeChat or contact information? I don't know how to use this website to socialize.

Comment: Yes, Chinese! Are you Chinese too?

Comment: Nice site where people discover eachother $\color{red}{+}$ mathematics !

Comment: yes I am Chinese, I want to learn from you,You’re so great in math There is also a selfless spirit of sharing

Comment: 嗯嗯 貌似是这个 我在准备研究生的考试  当初学的不太好  注意到外国的教材比较易懂，基础的东西想理解好，就来这问问题了  就发现您这位大佬

Comment: 是的  数学一要求高等数学 线性代数  概率论  高等数学占比最大 大概94分

Comment: 嗯嗯  讯飞输入法有个中译英的快捷翻译，还有有道词典，您才是真的大神，我这顶多会耍一些 小聪明。我对您的情况不太了解，对您的身份我很迷惑，从您的回复，我感觉您特别可爱，让我困惑您的性别。我菜的很，努力学习是从18年开始的，之前的我比较没有激情，初高中我学习困难选了文科，15年考上了山东的齐鲁工业大学，一直到18年学习困难才好一些，我读的会计专业，想跨专业到计算机科学，一直对它感兴趣，那时候没有勇气报这个专业，怕学不会，大学之前捣鼓过一些东西，觉得自己太垃圾了，各种各样的复杂的bug或者就是卡壳，跟着教程一遍又一遍的做，可能我脑子需要多动一动，需要变通灵活。我比较怪，想法做法有时比较“有毒“。

Comment: 真是一位年轻的能力强的老师。对于我来说我总把性别看的很重，这可能和我是记事以来是父亲带大的有关，父亲也比较沉默，所以现在的我，就比较怪，如果是女老师的话，我会不知所措，慌慌哒纠结地开心，男老师就会佩服变迷弟。

Comment: 删除中文聊天记录吧，这毕竟是英文的论坛！